# Passing Evercookie values out of the function

Tags: php, javascript

I'm totally stuck trying to get the best evercookie value out of the retrieval function and into a JS or PHP function I can use.

The code below works to trigger the alert for best_candidate, but I can't figure out how to return the value out of the function (I'm guessing the nested functions are what are tripping me up) so I can use the value outside the ec.get() function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
function getCookie(best_candidate, all_candidates)
{
    alert("The retrieved cookie is: " + best_candidate + "\n" +
        "You can see what each storage mechanism returned " +
        "by looping through the all_candidates object.");

     for (var item in all_candidates)
     {
         document.write("Storage mechanism " + item +
              " returned: " + all_candidates[item] + "<br>");
     }
}

ec.get("id", getCookie);
```

Comment: EverCookie is evil, why are you using it?

Answer (score -1):

This callback function with many parameters is designed for more specific needs.

All You need is:

```
var cookie;
ec.get("id", function(value) { cookie = value; });
```